# About RNN with variable length vectors

Tags: neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have several thousands samples with equal number of features (5000, they are time dependent) and I would like to predict of vectors with variable length.

I'm beginner in RNN, and I'd like to know if there are the approaches except zero padding, when we have  vector with variable length.

Comment: This might not be the right site for this. You may find more help at https://stats.stackexchange.com/